# Best way to declare a default for the reverse of a foreign key

Tags: sql, database-design, relational-database

A database with two tables and a foreign key relationship.

```
Person     Address
------     -----------
           person (fk)
```

In this example a person can have many addresses. How would it be best to declare a default address for a person? Are there any further pros or cons to the following 2 suggested options?

---

#### Option 1

Add a `boolean` field named `is_default` to the `Address` table.

#### Option 2

Add a `foreign key` field named `default_address` to the `Person` table.

---

Some thoughts on the two options.

- Use of constraints for either option

  - option 1, uniqueness constraint on the `person` and `is_default` attributes in the `Address` table
  - option 2, `default_address` attribute in the `Person` table is in the set of addresses which have that person as their person
- Option 2 would take less space to store in the database than option 1

---

The question also extends to the case where you would want to define more than one default address, i.e. a person may have one default shipping address and one default billing address. Using option 2 in this case would take less space to store in the database than option 1, and more so as you add more default fields.

---

One other thought on using option 2 is that an address being a default address or not is a property of the person, not the address.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with option 1 (keeping a default flag on the address table) is that you need code to enforce a limitation of default flags to one per person per type of default.  There are no declarative constraints that can help you do this.  A uniqueness constraint on the FK to person and your is-default flag won't work because you will have more than one non-default address per person potentially, and changing the is-default flag will always be a two-step process of unsetting the old default before setting the new default.

The issue with option 2 (FK from person to the default address) is that you have circular references.  This requires you to have code which manages the chicken and egg problem of saving an address and then making it the default in two separate transactions.  You also need code to ensure that the default address you set is an address belonging to the person (and not someone else).

Either way, you're going to have to write some application logic to make your selected option work.  It's up to you to pick your poison.  I've done this sort of thing both ways.  In the end I think your first option is a little easier to manage.